# Is it safe to use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler with Fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

Fabric does not seem to use it, NSSetUncaughtException Handler is NULL after initialization.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share what you're trying to accomplish? Having two UncaughtExceptionHandlers on iOS isn't supported and is not recommended.

Comment: Hi Mike, our app have "Reach Us" section that mails us complaints and our custom log file. We are trying to add crash logs to our log file.

Comment: Gotcha, that's good to know. What I'd recommend doing is add a user identifier to the Crashlytics crash report and then use that to find their crash when they contact you.

Comment: Hello again, we added custom identifier, thank you. But business side also wants to add crash to our custom log file. So i need to be sure NSSetUncaughtException will work with fabric without a problem.

Comment: You should only use one uncaught exception handler on iOS, I personally don't recommend the approach you're discussing.

Comment: @MikeBonnell We have SDK which we distribute to other users and we want to capture the crash logs of our sdk. We want to add the custom exception handler and after logging it we want to pass previous exception handler(might be crashalytics). Do you provide insights is it good idea and valid approach.

Comment: Please don't do this. Including Crashlytics SDK distributed to other teams is not permitted and will cause issues.